# Plotting based on column criteria in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

If i have a dataframe say

```
df = {'carx' : [merc,rari,merc,hond,fia,merc]
      'cary' : [bent,maz,ben,merc,fia,fia]
      'milesx' : [0,100,2,22,5,6]
      'milesy' : [10,3,18,2,19,2]}
```

I then would like to plot the value from column `milesx` if corresponding index of `carx` has the value 'merc'. The same criteria applies for `cary` and `milesy`, else nothing should be plotted. How can i do this?

`milesy` and `milesx` should be plotted on the x-axis. The y-axis should just be some continuous values (1,2...).

Comment: What are your axes? `milesx` and `milesy`?

Comment: Updated question. I went a little fast, when i asked it. My bad. @student

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, assuming you have following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline

# input dictionary
df = {'carx' : ['merc','rari','merc','hond','fia','merc'],
      'cary' : ['bent','maz','ben','merc','fia','fia'],
      'milesx' : [0,100,2,22,5,6],
      'milesy' : [10,3,18,2,19,2]}

# creating input dataframe
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(df)
print(dataframe)
```

Result:

```
   carx  cary  milesx  milesy
0  merc  bent       0      10
1  rari   maz     100       3
2  merc   ben       2      18
3  hond  merc      22       2
4   fia   fia       5      19
5  merc   fia       6       2
```

Then, you want to plot values given condition which can be done using function, and using `apply`:

```
def my_function(row):
    if row['carx'] == 'merc':return row['milesx']
    if row['cary'] == 'merc': return row['milesy']
    else: return None

# filter those with only 'merc'
filtered = dataframe.apply(lambda row: my_function(row), axis=1)
print(filtered)
```

Result:

```
0    0.0
1    NaN
2    2.0
3    2.0
4    NaN
5    6.0
dtype: float64
```

You do not want to plot when neither of them are which would be `NaN`, so `dropna()` may be used:

```
# plotting
filtered.dropna().plot(kind='bar', legend=None);
```

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Looks like no need to convert `Series` to `dataframe` for plotting.